# When are AJAX loaded DOM nodes "ready"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, dom-events

If in a web page I load some content after the initial page load and DOM ready event, when are the inserted nodes "ready", in the sense of having their sizes computed, taking CSS rules into consideration and all?

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    success: function (data) {

        var page = $(data).find('.page').first();

        page.appendTo(pages_container);

        // if I try to get the width of an element here, I get 0
        console.log(page.width()); // -> 0

        // but if I do it, let's say 500ms later, now it is computed
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(page.width()); // -> correct width, non zero
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Is there any kind of event, like "on inserted dom ready" or something to be able to execute a function *after* the sizes/layout of the ajax inserted content has been computed?

Comment: @KhorneHoly — The `success` parameter is not deprecated. You seem to be confusing it with the `success` method on an jqXHR object.

Comment: `onLoad` of the body tag is the event that gets triggered when all the resources including the dom structure is loaded on the page

Comment: @dreamweiver the body of the parent page? that would be weird... it doesn't as far as I can see.

Comment: Are you appending images? If so, you can't compute their width until they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should not occur as you outline. Appending elements into a page is not an asynchronous operation. Javascript DOM manipulation is not multi-threaded. It simply returns after the DOM changes have been applied.

The DOM *should* be ready to use as soon as your append completes (including size properties):

```
page.appendTo(pages_container);
```

The usual cause is accessing the properties before the jQuery object is inserted, or that the new jQuery object is visually hidden and revealed later (fadein etc), but I see no transitions in your code.

### Questions/thoughts:

- Can you mock up a JSFiddle to replicate your problem?
- Also check for other plugins etc that could modify your DOM after insertion.
- Is there JS code in the inserted page?
- Also what browser did this occur with?

Comment: actually yes, there is js code in the page, and the code that actually needs to get the width/height is itself *inside the loaded page* actually, but it happens the same in `success` and if I sprinkle around a few log statements, I see that indeed the code is run after success... it's a big faaaat page but I'll try to extract the problem in a fiddle

Comment: aaah, you mean that the code inside the html fragment inserted by ajax could actually be running before this fragment is inserted properly in the DOM? ...this would explain it ...but how the hell would could I solve this?

Comment: Yes, it may run the loaded JS on the disconnected element, as soon as you apply the `$(data)` call to the raw HTML/text loaded. Does the JS need to be inside the loaded page? Can you show the code within that page in case it is another issue?

Comment: Can't show the page, it's part of the admin interface to something. But I'll do a simpler mockup trying to replicate the problem when I have the time. For now I just found a specific ugly hack that allows me to avoid the problem entirely, but I'll still keep digging deeper for a solution/explanation to this...